# 2 methods with different parameters and exceptions

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch

I have 2 methods with different parameters:

```
await ocr.GetTextAsync(dataStream, filename, language);
```

and

```
await ocr.GetTextAsync(fileUrl, language);
```

both these methods can return the same list of exceptions. So, blocks like:

```
            try
            {
                 ocrResult = await ocr.GetTextAsync(dataStream, filename, language);
            }
            catch (FailedToProcessException failedEx)
            {
                _logger.AddLog("OCRController->GetTextAsync", $"Failed to process exception: '{failedEx.ErrorMessage}'", LogLevel.ERROR);
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, failedEx.ErrorMessage);
            }
            catch(InternalServerErrorException intEx)
            {
                _logger.AddLog("OCRController->GetTextAsync", $"Internal server error exception: '{intEx.ErrorMessage}'", LogLevel.ERROR);
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, intEx.ErrorMessage);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _logger.AddLog("OCRController->GetTextAsync", $"Exception: '{e.Message}'", LogLevel.ERROR);
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "File can't be processed");
            }
```

is similar. but I don't want to have "copy/paste" parts of code. How can I wrap it in one place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the method you want to be called as argument
Something like

```
private static async Task Try(Func<Task<Object>> methodToRun)
{
        try
        {
            object ocrResult = await methodToRun();
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
}

private static Task<object> Blabla(int v)
{
        throw new NotImplementedException();
}

private static Task<object> Blabla()
{
     throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

You can call it like this

```
await Try(() => Blabla());
await Try(() => Blabla(123));
```

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to be specific, lacking a question with a good [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows precisely what you're doing. But, something like the following should work:

```
async Task<ResponseType> SafeAwaitResult(Task<ResultType> task)
{
    try
    {
        ocrResult = await task;

        // do something to return a "success" value for ResponseType
    }
    catch (FailedToProcessException failedEx)
    {
        _logger.AddLog("OCRController->GetTextAsync", $"Failed to process exception: '{failedEx.ErrorMessage}'", LogLevel.ERROR);
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, failedEx.ErrorMessage);
    }
    catch(InternalServerErrorException intEx)
    {
        _logger.AddLog("OCRController->GetTextAsync", $"Internal server error exception: '{intEx.ErrorMessage}'", LogLevel.ERROR);
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, intEx.ErrorMessage);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        _logger.AddLog("OCRController->GetTextAsync", $"Exception: '{e.Message}'", LogLevel.ERROR);
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "File can't be processed");
    }
}
```

Then you can use it something like this:

```
ResponseType response =
    await SafeAwaitResult(ocr.GetTextAsync(dataStream, filename, language));
```

If you like, you could wrap that syntax in overloads:

```
Task<ResponseType> SafeAwaitResponse(Stream dataStream, string fileName, CultureInfo language)
{
    return SafeAwaitResult(ocr.GetTextAsync(dataStream, fileName, language))
}
```

I had to fill in a bunch of the types above, because your question isn't specific. Presumably, you can infer the correct actual syntax based on these examples. If not, please provide the necessary details in your question.